# Why do ``` and ''' produce outputs with different spaces?

Tags: punctuation

Why do

````
```
````

and

```
'''
```

produce outputs with different spaces?

[image]

````
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
Input:
\begin{verbatim}
```\\
'''
\end{verbatim}

Output:

```\\
'''
\end{document}
````

Comment: If you load `fontenc` with the `[T1]` encoding the spacing is the same for both.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The TeX Book mentions (**Chapter 2: Book Printing versus Ordinary Typing**, p 5): "There's usually less space *preceding* a single left quote than
there is preceding a double left quote. (Left and right are opposites.)"

As such, in the default Computer Modern font,

````
```\ \ldots\ '''
````

is interpreted as `“‘ ... ”’` that has an opening double quote and a closing single quote, resulting in incorrect spacing. In these instances, Knuth suggests using

[image]

```
Outer double, inner single: ``\thinspace`\ \ldots\ '\thinspace'' \par
Outer single, inner double: `\thinspace``\ \ldots\ ''\thinspace'
```