# How do you end with a single quote followed by a double quote?

Tags: punctuation, nesting

I have a paragraph as follows:

```
``This is a quote. `Here is a quote within a quote.'''
```

But the formatting works out to be a double quote (") followed by a single quote (') instead of the other way around. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Related: [Why do ``` and ''' produce outputs with different spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62127/5764)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have the following options:

[image]

```
Outer double, inner single: ``\thinspace`\ \ldots\ '\thinspace'' \par
Outer single, inner double: `\thinspace``\ \ldots\ ''\thinspace'
```

The TeX Book mentions (**Chapter 2: Book Printing versus Ordinary Typing**, p 5): "There's usually less space *preceding* a single left quote than there is preceding a double left quote. (Left and right are opposites.)"

So, in your instance,

```
``This is a quote. `Here is a quote within a quote.'\thinspace''
```

[image]

Comment: Would `\`\`{}\`Foo'{}''` be an option as well? It's kinda hard to tell, but the spaces do differ a bit between the "black marks" in the output. Considering you're quoting [Knuth's recommendation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62138/4012), it doesn't seem to be what was intended by the inventor.

Comment: @doncherry: To me the distinction is too minimal. However, I can see that it could be a user-preference as well.

Answer (score 19):

The [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package might be helpful.

For nested quotings just nest `\enquote{}` like this:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{outer and \enquote{inner}}
\end{document}
```

[image: nested enquotes (en)]

It is also very useful for non-english quotation marks:

```
\documentclass[naustrian,german]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{außen und \enquote{innen}}
\end{document}
```

[image: nested enquotes (de)]

Comment: +1, but German punctuation would prescribe `\enquote{innen}.}`, perhaps even `\enquote{innen}}.`. (On a side note: [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114))

Comment: @doncherry Thank you for your hints: I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: _Thank you for your hints: I edited my answer accordingly_ but not the result image, which confused me for a moment :-)

Answer (score 6):

````
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
``` '''     % misinterpretation by (La)TeX
``{}` '{}'' % good interpretation (but bad spaces) 
\end{document}
````

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution is use the `\,` command. It'll give you an output similar to the method using \thinspace.

Example:

```
``This is a quote \,`Here is a quote within a a quote.'\,''
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In fact, `\,` is defined exactly as `\thinspace` if not in math mode. And it's convenient to type, and the LaTeX documentation gives a similar example.

Comment: The example given is: `\`\`\,\`Foo', he said.''`