# How do I make ``` appear as ' + " and not "+ '?

Tags: punctuation

It may look like a minor difference, but I'm trying to put quotation marks between single quotes, e.g.

> ‘“go away” he said’

but `'''` results in

> “‘go away” he said’

which is not what I want...

Comment: Add an empty group `\`{}\`\``

Comment: Or better use the `csquotes` package and its command `\enquote` which nests correctly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73986/how-do-you-end-with-a-single-quote-followed-by-a-double-quote/73987#73987

Comment: @AndrewSwann: `csquotes` does not support it out if the box, because what he wants to do gives an unbalanced combination of `\enquote` and `\enquote*`

Comment: @Rico It does, you just have to choose the correct quote style.  The important point is that it makes the style at the inner level different to that at the outer level.

Comment: In the TeXbook, Knuth suggests writing `'\thinspace''`, for '+''.

Answer (score 14):

Explaining comment by @Andrew Swann

The package `csquotes` can help dealing with nested quotes and quoting styles in different languages.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
In English: \enquote{\enquote{Go away}, he said.}

\selectlanguage{russian}
На русском: \enquote{\enquote{Пошёл прочь!} --- сказал он}

\end{document}
```

This gets you following document:

[image: Preview]

Notice that Russian and English text has the same markup, but different presentation.

Comment: never the less its not what the Question Starter wanted. We would like to achieve those quotes like this SINGLE DOUBLE DOUBLE SINGLE. What you did gives him the normal DOUBLE SINGLE SINGLE DOUBLE.

Comment: Changing `english=american` to `english=british` does the right thing. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: right this fixes the problem got my +1

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way is to add a pair of curly braces between the first and second backtick, which tells LaTeX to split them as a single, followed by a double. That is, write

```
`{}``Go away'', he said'
```

as opposed to

````
```Go away'', he said'
````

You get the following result:

[image]